# Login Form does not work if I require HTTPS (Symfony3)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2

I would like to create a [login form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html), and require https for all pages of my website.

My `security.yml` looks like this:

```
access_control:
    #- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }

    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/logout, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

It works, but if I remove the `#` sign from the beginnig of the first line, the authentication stops working. The security system does not intercept the request. I have many lines in my `access_control`, so it would be inpractical to define it for each page.

My main goal is: Require https for all pages. Each page should be only available for logged in users, except for `login`, `index` and a few

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Symfony read your access control, it takes the first path that match with the route called.  So if you defined (as you did) the path `^/` (which match every routes) first, SF will just not read your `login` or `logout` access control. [See this part of cookbook](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html#avoid-common-pitfalls)

If you want your website full https, I suggest to edit your nginx, apache config to redirect users who typed `http` to `https` :

```
# example with nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  yourwebsite.com;
    return       301 https://yourwebsite.com$request_uri;
}
```